# mysql print data to display to html

Tags: php, html, mysql

i've got a basic php script that's connects to mysql and print data but i'm having issues making it print via html the html i have atm this is only part of the html only the important part.
Sorry i have to type lots of crap so you can see this code because stackoverflow is such an amazing website, It helps lots and lots of people

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "toor";
$dbname = "a3wasteland";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT UID, BattlEyeGUID, CreationDate, Name, BankMoney FROM PlayerInfo";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

?>
<div class='cWidgetContainer ipsHide' data-controller='core.front.widgets.area' data-role='widgetReceiver' data-orientation='horizontal' data-widgetArea='header'>
    <ul class='ipsList_reset'>

    </ul>
  </div>


<div id="elCmsPageWrap" data-pageid="2">

<div>
  <div class='ipsGrid ipsGrid_collapsePhone'>
    <div class='ipsGrid_span6'>



  <div class='cWidgetContainer ipsHide' data-controller='core.front.widgets.area' data-role='widgetReceiver' data-orientation='horizontal' data-widgetArea='col1'>
    <ul class='ipsList_reset'>

    </ul>
  </div>

    </div>
    <div class='ipsGrid_span6'>



  <div class='cWidgetContainer ipsHide' data-controller='core.front.widgets.area' data-role='widgetReceiver' data-orientation='horizontal' data-widgetArea='col2'>
    <ul class='ipsList_reset'>

    </ul>
  </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>



  <div class='cWidgetContainer ' data-controller='core.front.widgets.area' data-role='widgetReceiver' data-orientation='horizontal' data-widgetArea='footer'>
    <ul class='ipsList_reset'>


          <li class='ipsWidget ipsWidget_horizontal ipsBox' data-blockID='plugin_20_sodPhpWidget_paxe9xcu5' data-blockConfig="true" data-blockTitle="PHP Code" data-controller='core.front.widgets.block'>

<div class='ipsWidget_inner '>


    <p class='ipsType_reset ipsType_medium ipsType_light'>  
  <style>
  .specialType_center th {
    text-align: center; 
  }
  </style>
</style>
  <h2 class="ipsType_sectionTitle ipsType_reset cForumTitle ipsResponsive_hideTablet ipsResponsive_hidePhone <center> ">Banned Users</h2></center>
    <table class="ipsTable ipsTable_responsive ipsTable_zebra ipsBox ipsType_center specialType_center ipsResponsive_hideTablet ipsResponsive_hidePhone">
      <thead> 
   <tr>
      <th>UID</th>
      <th>BattlEyeGUID</th>
      <th>CreationDate</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>BankMoney</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<?php
/* Other code */
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
        <td><span class="ipsType_negative"><?=$row["UID"]?></span></td></tr>
        <td><span class="ipsType_negative"><?=$row["BattlEyeGUID"]?></span></td>
        <td><span class="ipsType_negative"><?=$row["CreationDate"]?></span></td>
        <td><span class="ipsType_negative"><?=$row["Name"]?></span></td>
        <td><span class="ipsType_negative"><?=$row["BankMoney"]?></span></td>
<?php } 
} else { ?>
    <td colspan="5">0 results</td>
<?php } ?>
</tr>
</tbody>
    </table>
  <p class='ipsType_right ipsType_light ipsType_small ipsResponsive_hideTablet ipsResponsive_hidePhone' style='margin-right: 10px;'>Last Update: 15.08.2016, 10:41 </p>
</p>

</div></li>

</ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: use `<tr><td>....` inside the while loop.

Comment: where is the loop i'm terrible at coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<thead> 
   <tr>
      <th>PlayerUID</th>
      <th>PlayerKills</th>
      <th>AIKILLs</th>
      <th>TeamKills</th>
      <th>DeathCount</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php
/* Other code */
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
 <tr>     <!-- start tr within the loop -->
   <td><?php echo $row["PlayerUID"]; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row["PlayerKills"]; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row["AIKILLs"]; ?></td>
   <td> <!-- Other data --></td>
   <td><!-- Other data --></td>
</tr>     <!-- end tr within the loop -->
<?php } 
} else { ?>
    <tr><td colspan="5">0 results</td></tr> 
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: You should put it on top of the page.

Comment: It's hard to understand with the columns overlapping. Add a table border: <table border="1">

Comment: The tr should be within the while loop. Let me edit my answer

Comment: U r using extra tr

Answer (score 0):

You can print your data inside the html like:

**Your While code block:**

```
<?php
// use <tr><td></td></tr> inside the loop.
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="ipsType_negative"><?=$row["PlayerUID"]?></span></td>
        <td><span class="ipsType_negative"><?=$row["PlayerKills"]?></span></td>
        <td><span class="ipsType_negative"><?=$row["AIKILLs"]?></span></td>
        <td><span class="ipsType_negative">TeamKills</span></td>
        <td><span class="ipsType_negative">DeathCount</span></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: just trying to figure out how to fix the first data entry it only shows the uid and the last entry shows everything but the uid you know why?

Answer (score 0):

The finishing code

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "toor";
$dbname = "a3wasteland";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT UID, BattlEyeGUID, CreationDate, Name, BankMoney FROM PlayerInfo";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

?>
<div class='cWidgetContainer ipsHide' data-controller='core.front.widgets.area' data-role='widgetReceiver' data-orientation='horizontal' data-widgetArea='header'>
    <ul class='ipsList_reset'>

    </ul>
  </div>


<div id="elCmsPageWrap" data-pageid="2">

<div>
  <div class='ipsGrid ipsGrid_collapsePhone'>
    <div class='ipsGrid_span6'>



  <div class='cWidgetContainer ipsHide' data-controller='core.front.widgets.area' data-role='widgetReceiver' data-orientation='horizontal' data-widgetArea='col1'>
    <ul class='ipsList_reset'>

    </ul>
  </div>

    </div>
    <div class='ipsGrid_span6'>



  <div class='cWidgetContainer ipsHide' data-controller='core.front.widgets.area' data-role='widgetReceiver' data-orientation='horizontal' data-widgetArea='col2'>
    <ul class='ipsList_reset'>

    </ul>
  </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>



  <div class='cWidgetContainer ' data-controller='core.front.widgets.area' data-role='widgetReceiver' data-orientation='horizontal' data-widgetArea='footer'>
    <ul class='ipsList_reset'>


          <li class='ipsWidget ipsWidget_horizontal ipsBox' data-blockID='plugin_20_sodPhpWidget_paxe9xcu5' data-blockConfig="true" data-blockTitle="PHP Code" data-controller='core.front.widgets.block'>

<div class='ipsWidget_inner '>


    <p class='ipsType_reset ipsType_medium ipsType_light'>  
  <style>
  .specialType_center th {
    text-align: center; 
  }
  </style>
</style>
  <h2 class="ipsType_sectionTitle ipsType_reset cForumTitle ipsResponsive_hideTablet ipsResponsive_hidePhone <center> ">Arma 3 Player Stats</h2></center>
    <table class="ipsTable ipsTable_responsive ipsTable_zebra ipsBox ipsType_center specialType_center ipsResponsive_hideTablet ipsResponsive_hidePhone">
      <thead> 


   <tr>
      <th>BattlEyeGUID</th>
      <th>CreationDate</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>BankMoney</th>
      <th>UID</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<?php
/* Other code */
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
        <td><span class="ipsType_negative"><?=$row["UID"]?></span></td></tr>
        <td><span class="ipsType_negative"><?=$row["BattlEyeGUID"]?></span></td>
        <td><span class="ipsType_negative"><?=$row["CreationDate"]?></span></td>
        <td><span class="ipsType_negative"><?=$row["Name"]?></span></td>
        <td><span class="ipsType_negative"><?=$row["BankMoney"]?></span></td>
<?php } 
} else { ?>
    <td colspan="5">0 results</td>
<?php } ?>
</tr>
</tbody>
    </table>
  <p class='ipsType_right ipsType_light ipsType_small ipsResponsive_hideTablet ipsResponsive_hidePhone' style='margin-right: 10px;'>Last Update: 15.08.2016, 10:41 </p>
</p>

</div></li>

</ul>
  </div>
```